# insert data into a database with prepared statements pdo

Tags: php

I changed the code so that i can insert directly into the database. Now I face an issue with line of code `$database->bindParam(':name', $name[0][$i]);`. Which gives me the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam()` How can I fix this?

```
$hostname = 'XXX';
$database = 'XXX';
$username = 'XXX';
$password = 'XXX';
$database = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

function get_data($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}

$html = get_data($_GET['url']);
preg_match_all('/\<font face\=\"Arial\"\>\<strong\>(.*)\<br\>\<font color/', $html, $name);
preg_match('/\<strong\>([A-Z\s0-9]+) BIRTHDAYS\<\/strong\>/', $html, $date);

for ($i=0, $n=count($name[1]); $i<$n; ++$i) {       
        try {
            $insert = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO bday (name, birthdate) VALUES (:name, :date)");

            $database->bindParam(':name', $name[0][$i]);
            $database->bindParam(':date', $date[1]);

            $insert->execute();
        }

        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
}
```

Comment: simple insert with an auto increment primary key, the db will take care of the rest

Answer (score 1):

First fetch the content:

```
$content = file_get_contents('filename');
```

Get each line:

```
$line = explode('\n', $contents);
```

Now you have each line in an array; loop through each, explode it again on comma and insert to DB

```
$ct = count($arr);
while($i < $ct) 
{
     $arr = explode(',', $line[$i]);
     /* Insert into database value $i, $arr[1], $arr[2], just ignore $arr[0] which contains your original string */
     $i++;
}
```

Comment: the data is actually in a text file not in the database yet

Comment: thanks i changed the code to add directly to the database can you take a look at it now?

Comment: @bammab Though I have no experience with PDO.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the database have a primary key which auto increments so you don't have to worry about it but if that isn't possible just throw it in a for loop:

```
$array = explode("\n",file_get_contents("file.txt"));
foreach($array as $count => $line) {
    $array[$count] = str_replace('xxx',$count+1,$line);
}
```